# Codeigniter session different site

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Hi all I have two sites developed in codeigniter. These sites are completely different but the mdoel of user is similar like the login method because I thinked to recycle that code.
The problem is: If I log in into a site and open the other I am logged in inside it with the user of the other site that doesn't exist into my database.
Database are different, I don't know what is the problem or if I have to change my login method into my model or some configuration.

This is my method in the model:

```
function login($username = '', $password = '') {
        $user_name = base64_decode($username);
        $password  = base64_decode($password);

        //Make sure login info was sent
        if($username == '' || $password == '') {
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Check if already logged in
        if( $this->session->userdata('username') == $username && $this->session->userdata('logged_in') ) {
            //User is already logged in.
            return TRUE;
        }
        //Check against user table
        $this->db->where('username', $user_name);
        $this->db->where('password', $this->encrypt->sha1($password) );
        $this->db->where('active', 1);

        $query = $this->db->get_where($this->user_table);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row_array(); 

            //Destroy old session
            $this->session->sess_destroy();

            //Create a fresh, brand new session
            $this->session->sess_create();

            //Update Last Login
            $data = array(
               'last_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            );

            $this->db->where('id', $row['id']);
            $this->db->update($this->user_table, $data); 

            //Set session data
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('id' => $row['id'], 'username' => $row['username'],'name' => $row['name'], 'surname' => $row['surname'], 'language' => $row['language']));

            if ($row['type']==1){
                //se è 1 è un administrator
                $this->session->set_userdata(array('is_admin' => 1));   
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_userdata(array('is_admin' => 0));
            }

            //Set logged_in to true
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('logged_in' => TRUE));   

            //image profile
            $this->db->where('user_id', $row['id']);

            $query2 = $this->db->get_where('user_image_profile');
            if ($query2->num_rows() > 0) {
                $row_image = $query2->row_array(); 
                $this->session->set_userdata(array('img_profile' => $row_image['filename']));
            }       

            //Login was successful          
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            //No database result found
            return FALSE;
        }   
     }
```

Comment: Are both sites running on same domain?

Comment: Yes because is in my demo server

Comment: Does Sharif Ul Islam's solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `config` file. Here you use the same "encryption_key" for the both site for that reason when you log in one site and open the other one here you also logged. So you have to use different "encryption_key" for the both site.

like that for first web site-

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'gHZc2let11sp3YAns00rggHlYNMp7CVX';
```

and the second one -

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'V1M839GlUk65rKzm1GM67H66X1WLD6ay';
```

Answer (score 0):

for each application you can configure the session to be stored in the database. change config file.

```
sess_use_database = true;
```

after that you need to create this table in your database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address VARCHAR(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```